# Python Dictionary keys with nested list to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, concatenation

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
D = {
    'd1': [[a1, a1, a1], [a2, a2, a2], [a3, a3, a3]], 
    'd2': [[b1, b1, b1], [b2, b2, b2], [b3, b3, b3]], 
    'd3': [[c1, c1, c1], [c2, c2, c2], [c3, c3, c3]], 
    'd4': [[d1, d1, d1], [d2, d2, d2], [d3, d3, d3]]
}
```

How do I convert it to a dataframe such that

- The columns from the lists for a key are paired up; the nested lists are time values, temperatures and damage values, respectively, and the dataframe needs to have these in separate columns. S for `[[a1, a1, a1], [a2, a2, a2], [a3, a3, a3]]`, you'd get a row with `a1, a2, a3` (first column), followed by a row for the 2nd column, etc.
- The dataframe rows are grouped by combining keys with the next key, `d1` combined with `d2` make 6 rows (3 from `d1` and 3 from `d2`), then `d2` is combined with `d3` to make 6 more rows, etc. So for the 4 keys with 3 rows each, you get 3 combinations of 6 rows == 18 rows.

I tried converting to a dataframe before concatenating:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(list(D.values()), columns=['Time_sec', 'Temperature', 'Damage'])
```

but I am still stuck with concatenating part.

[image]

Sample expected output:

[image: Expected output DataFrame]

Comment: So are those `a1`, `a2`, etc references actually floating point numbers?

Comment: Could you edit the post to add an example of what output do you expect?

Comment: Can you give us a small sample of the expected output?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes they are floating point numbers

Comment: just seen that link

Comment: Please make that text, if at all possible.

Comment: Right, so you want to *zip* the nested lists. Note that dictionaries are not really ordered; do you need to sort by keys here?

Comment: I was thinking of a for loop to perform the zipping and sorting based on keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) together each sublist for a given key, to form new rows with values from each sublist combined:

```
>>> list(zip(*D['d1']))
[('a1', 'a2', 'a3'), ('a1', 'a2', 'a3'), ('a1', 'a2', 'a3')]
```

then apply this to every value in the dictionary to produce a flattened sequence of rows, where you pick your pairings.

I'm assuming you want to pair up `dN` with `dN+1` here, regardless of the number of keys. Note that dictionaries are actually *unordered* (although Python 3.6 and up insertion order is preserved), so you may want to apply some sorting first:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(D)
```

after which we can pair them up with `zip(sorted_keys, sorted_keys[1:])`:

```
>>> sorted_keys = sorted(D)
>>> list(zip(sorted_keys, sorted_keys[1:]))
[('d1', 'd2'), ('d2', 'd3'), ('d3', 'd4')]
```

Use this sequence to pair up the rows and flatten the resulting key sequence, then the zipped rows:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(D)
paired = (k for keys in zip(sorted_keys, sorted_keys[1:]) for k in keys)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    (row for k in paired for row in zip(*D[k])), 
    columns=['Time_sec', 'Temperature', 'Damage']
)
```

This produces:

```
   Time_sec Temperature Damage
0        a1          a2     a3
1        a1          a2     a3
2        a1          a2     a3
3        b1          b2     b3
4        b1          b2     b3
5        b1          b2     b3
6        b1          b2     b3
7        b1          b2     b3
8        b1          b2     b3
9        c1          c2     c3
10       c1          c2     c3
11       c1          c2     c3
12       c1          c2     c3
13       c1          c2     c3
14       c1          c2     c3
15       d1          d2     d3
16       d1          d2     d3
17       d1          d2     d3
```

Comment: Thanks for sugesstion but the dictionary keys are to be appended first then converted to dataframe. there is a difference between your output and my expected output as you can see my 'b' and 'c' values are repeated in the output

Comment: @RaziurRahman: then your question is entirely unclear. How does the output in my answer differ from your screenshot?

Comment: the key order should be d1 d2 d2 d3 d3 d4

Comment: @RaziurRahman: that's not clear *at all*. By what rules are the keys repeating?

Comment: @RaziurRahman: is that the part where you wanted `d1 + d2` being the first set of rows, followed by `d2 + d3`, etc.? What if there are 10 keys? Or just 1?

Comment: after thre times b1 i have again 3 times b1 then comes c1.. remember i said d1+d2 --> d2+d3 ---> d3+d4

Comment: yes first set of rows d1+d2 followed by d2+d3.. irrespective of number of keys.. if i have 11 keys then the last key will just be concatenated to the output dataframe

Comment: @RaziurRahman: why would the last key not be paired up with the preceding key when you have 11?

Comment: extremely sorry for the last line ... ignore it... I posted because I could not find a way to append two values of two keys of a single dictionary and converting them to a DataFrame..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer... especially the paried variable where you took the pairs...

Comment: @MartijnPieters was my question too sloppy to receive a -1 ? I dont know.. anyways i got what i needed.. thanks a lot man...

Comment: @RaziurRahman: I can't read people's minds, sorry. I can't tell you why someone votes the way they do.

Answer (score 0):

Using enumerate

```
l = ['Time', 'Temperature', 'Damage']
d2 = {}

for idx, item in enumerate(l):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if item not in d2:
            d2[item] = v[idx]
        else:
            d2[item] += v[idx]
```

> ```
> {'Time': ['a1, a1, a1', 'b1, b1, b1', 'c1, c1, c1', 'd1, d1, d1'],
> 'Temperature': ['a2, a2, a2', 'b2, b2, b2', 'c2, c2, c2', 'd2, d2,
> d2'], 'Damage': ['a3, a3, a3', 'b3, b3, b3', 'c3, c3, c3', 'd3, d3,
> d3']}
> ```

Using pseudo values

```
a1, a2, a3  = 0, 'a', '!'
b1, b2, b3  = 0, 'a', '!'
c1, c2, c3  = 0, 'a', '!'
d1, d2, d3  = 0, 'a', '!'
```

> ```
> {'Time': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'Temperature': ['a',
> 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 'Damage':
> ['!', '!', '!', '!', '!', '!', '!', '!', '!', '!', '!', '!']}
> ```

Comment: No.. Please be see the expected output

Comment: How about this ?

Comment: I had to make your variables strings but you would do this without them being strings

Comment: @RaziurRahman I saw you did not want that an undeleted, is this not suitable will take down if so